# Find the number to replace the question mark in between two pairs of numbers

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle, pattern-recognition

Here is the problem:

[image: This is the Problem]

I have to find the number to replace the question mark. 
I know there is a series or a pattern to find it any hint will be very helpful.

Comment: I am not sure what this kind of question is called

Answer (score 3):

$2+4+6+0-2=10$ and $8+10+2+6-2=24$ so $x=10+12+14+4-2$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what the question is looking for, but in the first two examples, the middle number is closely related to the sum of the four other numbers.